# Replace a Subquery in a SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I'm working in MS Access and there is a huge Query, which is needed to collect Data from many different tables.
In this Query i work with some subqueries and by now this works pretty fine.

But now i want to replace those subqueries, because they are not avaialable in every database i work with.

This is the SQL Query i work with:

```
SELECT 
Left([INPUT_BASIC_ELEMENT_DATA].[TO_NODE_NAME],7) & "Test" & Right([INPUT_BASIC_ELEMENT_DATA].[TO_NODE_NAME],3) AS su_nr, 
INPUT_BASIC_ELEMENT_DATA.FROM_NODE_NAME AS SupportFunction,  
CLEAN.su_clean_load_Fx, CLEAN.su_clean_load_Fy,CLEAN.su_clean_load_Fz, 
CLEAN.su_clean_move_max_Dx, CLEAN.su_clean_move_max_Dy, CLEAN.su_clean_move_max_Dz
FROM (((((((INPUT_BASIC_ELEMENT_DATA LEFT JOIN INPUT_BASIC_ELEMENT_DATA AS INPUT_BASIC_ELEMENT_DATA_1 ON INPUT_BASIC_ELEMENT_DATA.TO_NODE_NAME = INPUT_BASIC_ELEMENT_DATA_1.FROM_NODE_NAME) LEFT JOIN CLEAN ON INPUT_BASIC_ELEMENT_DATA.TO_NODE_NAME = CLEAN.NODE_NAME) )))))
WHERE (((Len([INPUT_BASIC_ELEMENT_DATA].[TO_NODE_NAME]))="10"));
```

As you can see i work with a subquery which is called CLEAN

This subquery is doing this:

```
SELECT OUTPUT_RESTRAINTS_SUMMARY.NODE_NAME, OUTPUT_RESTRAINTS_SUMMARY.FX AS su_clean_load_Fx, OUTPUT_RESTRAINTS_SUMMARY.FY AS su_clean_load_Fy, OUTPUT_RESTRAINTS_SUMMARY.FZ AS su_clean_load_Fz, OUTPUT_RESTRAINTS_SUMMARY.MX AS su_clean_move_max_Dx, OUTPUT_RESTRAINTS_SUMMARY.MY AS su_clean_move_max_Dy, OUTPUT_RESTRAINTS_SUMMARY.MZ AS su_clean_move_max_Dz
FROM OUTPUT_RESTRAINTS_SUMMARY
WHERE (((OUTPUT_RESTRAINTS_SUMMARY.LCASE_NAME) Like "*CLEAN*"));
```

How can i work without subqueries in my upper Query ?

I think i need to copy a part or whole subquery and paste it into my SQL Statement.
But i dont know how to do it.

Hope you can help me.

Greetings.

Comment: Whether subquery is a separate query object or nested SQL, you still have a subquery. What do you mean by 'not available in every database'? Really not understanding issue. Copy subquery SQL (without semicolon) then paste it into other query between parens: `LEFT JOIN (subquery SQL here) AS Clean ON`.

Comment: At first i have to thank you for your answer. 
Im not that into SQL and querries, so maybe it was a stupid question.
But you helped me to fix it. 

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy subquery SQL (without semicolon) then paste it into other query between parens:

`... LEFT JOIN (subquery SQL here) AS Clean ON ...`.

Then can delete `Clean` query object .